# Collectives member count is way off

Tags: bug, collectives

Taking for example [Google Cloud Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud), it says "View all 96 Members":

[image: Google Cloud Collective showing View all 96 Members]

However, after clicking it, I see table with only 23 users:

[image: Only 23 members in table]

Can this please become consistent, either way?

Note this applies to all Collectives, e.g. also happens with [Go Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/go), it's **NOT** specific to a single Collective.

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Easy fix: *View all 6 to 8 Members*

Comment: @rene is jesting, but... "View all members", "View more members", and "View additional members" would all be acceptable ways of deftly avoiding needing to make an actual count here, and would be strongly preferable to a *wrong* count. (Can you tell I've finessed around similar bugs before? Anyone?)

Comment: I'm dead serious ....

Answer (score 2):

Yes because it was updated 15 hours ago:

[image]

---

***Update: the list is updated now!***

Comment: This is correct. The leaderboard will updated once every 24 hours. Check back in 9 hours for a more accurate count :)

Comment: I presume this is also when all of the Stack Overflow employees (who were presumably added for testing purposes) will be removed as members from this collective?

Comment: Maybe, but it's still super confusing. @PiperLawson no, in 9 hours the members count showing in the Collective itself will be much higher, even now, only 20 minutes later it's already 113. And I have no idea what it really means. All I want is to see same number, not start to calculate times and vectors. It's a horrible UX.

Comment: it's updated now @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2

Comment: @PeterHaddad still off by 15, which is better, and says "Last updated 17 hours ago" so something still off. Like I said to Piper, having it different on purpose due to one number being cached and one live is very bad user experience. Legit, but just does not look professional at all.