# Are Collective icons too conspicuous?

Tags: discussion, design, collectives

I feel GitLab's collective icon is disrupting the harmony of the questions page. Just look how striking it is on the light theme:

[image: The GitLab icon in light mode has a dark blue background.]

Also, the Google Cloud icon has a similar issue on the dark theme (but to a lesser degree):

[image: The Google Cloud icon in dark mode has a white background.]

I believe these are too eye-catching and possibly need some regulations; probably less-contrast icons or maybe different icons for different themes.

Comment: You can also run a script that just removes them :)

Comment: I'd love to see a script that deletes collectives from the site

Comment: `truncate table collectives`

Comment: Everything about that collective smells... meh... Kind of reminds me of the *Borg*... "*We are the Borg. Lower your shields and surrender your ships... We pay to advertise as content... Resistance is Futile*" Can we just delete the whole concept and pretend its still a thing?

Comment: While I do agree with the sentiment, I guess this is [meta-tag:status-by-design]? The icons sticking out as much as possible is very likely to be an intentional choice..

Comment: I was surprised to find out that the URL for Google Cloud on dark mode is `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/subcommunities/google-cloud-dark.svg`, implying that SO already supports different icons for light/dark mode.

Comment: @AndrewT. Nice bit of sherlocking, but what Oleg says sounds very believable. We have to keep in mind that collections are a *product*, not a site feature for our benefit.

Comment: They are meant to be _eye-catching_

Comment: @Zoe Just search on the Stack Exchange script store: [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com)

Comment: They are so conspicious when I see one I can't help downvoting the question it's attached to.

Comment: @oguzismail I hope you're not serious about that last part 

Comment: @Zoe A browser extension to hide them would be more practical :D

Comment: it's almost as if they're meant to raise brand awareness or something

Comment: @Cerbrus It should be `drop table collectives`.

Comment: I heard they are going to rename them from collectives to garbagey (a new word too).

Comment: @Alejandro Removing a whole table is much more likely to make a server fail to start, whereas I would assume that they handle the case where there are just zero items.

Comment: A [userscript from Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/9033/removing-collectives-from-stack-overflow) for removing collectives.

Comment: Even if done on purpose, I think having a white background in what's supposed to be dark mode is a problem. The whole point of dark mode is to not blind people with bright, white light.

Comment: Add one of "themed subcommunity-avatar subcommunity-google-cloud" to AdBlock style lists, ex. "stackoverflow.com##.subcommunity-avatar" filter rule in uBlock Origin

Comment: What do this icon even mean? Does it depend on tag (e.g. "gitlab"), or did someone pay to get more visibility for their question?

Comment: @EricDuminil option #1 - each collective has a set of tags "associated" with them

Comment: The [go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnNke.png) badge is super bright too. Also, it's too bad there wasn't a [gadget] tag applied to this, so it could have read [go] [go] [gadget] [factory].

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="/collective"]').forEach(el => el.remove() )`

Comment: This is a matter of opinion, and being conspicuous is certainly the *point* of having a special icon in the first place. Voting to close.

Comment: @TylerH I thought the point of meta was to discuss thing and share opinons.

Comment: @Scratte Meta is a place to discuss things and share differing viewpoints, yes, but posting a discussion asking if something is "too conspicuous" is not something that *useful* opinions can be shared around, and as I mentioned it misses the fact that conspicuousness is the entire point of the feature. Opinions are useful if they can be backed up with useful data or perspectives. Here, though, it's just a case of pure whim.

Comment: @TylerH How about if there's consensus, then we can get rid of them entirely? Some of us would like that.

Comment: @Scratte There is already a fairly consensus among the community that Collectives are bad, but the community consensus on Collectives is irrelevant, because it's a product the company has chosen to pursue. As has been documented numerous times recently, what the community wants is not considered in terms of big decisions where the network is concerned. Aside from that, a feature request to make an icon less conspicuous won't do anything to remove Collectives from the site altogether, so that's a non sequitur.

Comment: "non sequitur" meaning "absurd to the point of being humorous or confusing". That's just your opinion. Funny how that works.

Comment: @TylerH No. it is useful, SO staff will notice it, they will inform the related product owner, they will inform the designer, and they will upload new Icons. All happened because they can see the what other people are thinking. This is human centered website, and people should be comfortable spending time in it

Comment: @Scratte Uh, what? Non sequitur means "does not follow logically". For example, "I drove my car to work today instead of taking the train, so I don't know who painted the Mona Lisa." Opinion has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A That's a nice pipe dream, but it's not a reflection of reality, unfortunately. If SO listened to community on such matters over their own desires, we'd still have the old profile page layout, Collectives would be removed completely, Monica would be reinstated as moderator everywhere, gold-badge Mjolnir powers would cover other close reasons, et cetera, ad infinitum. None of those things are the case, despite massive Community clamoring for each one (and that's far from an exhaustive list).

Comment: The icon is not "disrupting the harmony of the questions page" - the huge amount of absolute garbage questions is disrupting the harmony of the question page. The icon just makes the design look inconsistent, which is an afterthought at this point in time. The term "lipstick on a pig" comes to mind...

Comment: These icons do not really add any value to the visitor in any way, at least I don't see any. It's okay to block them, I'd say.

Answer (score 28):

If you have a plugin like [User Javascript and CSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld)

you can use a css rule like:

```css
.subcommunity-avatar.s-avatar {
   filter: grayscale(1);
}
.subcommunity-google-cloud.s-avatar,
.subcommunity-go.s-avatar {
    filter: invert(1) grayscale(1);
}
```

[image: preview of grayscale icon]
[image: preview of google cloud]

Personally I find it suited better than the brighter icons for  groups that I have no affinity with, but I kinda like the markings, but not the bright colors.

If you wish to go nuclear, just hide them:

```css
.subcommunity-avatar.s-avatar {
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: btw here is the selector `a[href^="/collective"]` for collective icons

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A I think you also posted a similar comment on the Question. Doesn't it find for example links to [Collective Article downvote pushes for explanation. Bug or new feature?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408656/collective-article-downvote-pushes-for-explanation-bug-or-new-feature) and [Collectives member count is way off](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408604/collectives-member-count-is-way-off)

Comment: Bonus points for actually solving the mentioned problem rather than just nuking the icons entirely.

Comment: @Gimby I'd give bonus points for actually nuking the icons, and anything related to Collectives. To each their own.

Comment: @EricDuminil `display:none` is always an option though