# GitLab tag has a white border on the side in dark-mode

Tags: bug, tags, dark-mode, collectives

As the title says, if you click on [gitlab tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gitlab), this is what I see. There is a white line on the right side of the tag, and sometimes on the bottom, too:

[image]

Windows, Google Chrome version: Version 94.0.4606.71 (Official Build) (64-bit)

---

**Edit:** As clarified in the comments this (only) happens when zoomed at 110%.

Comment: That look like a background.. :/

Comment: Somewhat related: [Are Collective icons too conspicuous?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411778/8967612)

Comment: I don't see the white stripe on Firefox 93. Probably a Chrome thing...

Comment: [No repro here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy6FS.png) (Chrome 94.0.4606.81 on Windows).

Comment: I would check your zoom and desktop scaling settings for the inconsistency. It has already been reported that [the left side never shows the background](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411913).

Comment: @Nick Correct, yes it was zoomed at 110%. (I never use Zoom, must have zoomed by mistake) Shall we close as duplicate of your link?

Comment: @zx8754 Nah, I think that bug report is very poorly placed, because it's not an issue with high contrast mode (as you can see as you're not using it), I think just adjust this post to be a bug report stating that the GitLab tag has a white background